# More Pathfinder Kaiju

Tags: pathfinder-1e, golarion

I was wondering if anyone knew if there were more kaiju that have been fully detailed (statted out and given background write ups) aside from Agmazar, Agyra, Bezraunis and Mogaru that are from official Golarion. In the original entry in Bestiary 4 about kaiju there was a sidebar entry titled "Known Kaiju" that went,

> The kaiju presented on the following pages are but three of the legendary creatures said to dwell in remote places in the world. Here is a list of others, including the places they're rumored to dwell.
>
> - Agmazar, the Star Titan of the vast jungle
> - Cimurlian, the Great Bear of the frozen north
> - Ebeshra, the Winged Razor of the furthest clouds
> - Igroon, the Dragon Eater of the lost island
> - Mantraska, the World Talons of the rain forest
> - Shbloon, the Vortex Maw of the ocean deep
> - Lord Varklops, the Thrice-Headed Fiend of the dormant volcano
> - Queen Vorgozen, the Shapeless Feeder of the vast swamp
> - Yarthoon, the Moon Grub of the darkest nights
> - Yorak, the Horned Thunder of the great mountains
> - Zimivra, the Endless Coils of the trackless desert

<sup>(bullet points added to play nice with SE format)</sup>

Now I know Agmazar was detailed in Mythic Realms but were there (or are they announced to be...) any more detailed in other books? (Yes I know about Kaiju Codex from Rite Publishing but I am curious about official ones on Golarion or from the surrounding star system.)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that is it for Paizo official stat blocks for Kaiju. The others are there for reference if you wish to create them, though they may still come out. (They did the same thing for demon/devil lords long ago and they are now being published)

However, look forward to the upcoming [Pathfinder Bestiary 6](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9r1y?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Bestiary-6), where there is a chance they'll add some, though none have been announced for it.

Comment: Bestiary 6 stats Lord Varklops, Queen Vorgozen, and Yarthoon.